# Div not filling 100% height

Tags: html, css, height

I seem to have a problem that my container div is not getting 100% height to the bottom of the page. You can see the layout at http://jsfiddle.net/hqC3U/

I've tried everything from min-height till dirty old hacks that did not work.

Is there anybody with some advise?

Comment: May I ask why you're using tables to lay your web page out?

Comment: You start with a div, but the next element is a `<tr>`. Try using divs in the layout instead of tables and make sure your code is valid.

Comment: div based layouts are easy to operate so try to make the layouts in div........

Comment: Thank you everybody. I'll go try and convert them to div's.

Comment: yup sure and than if u will face any kind of problem we are here for you buddy to sort the bugs....

Comment: Stop using tables, You make the net so ugly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant apply a percent value to div height, because theoretically your height could be infinite. You will have to use something like min-height.

Comment: looks like this is what twitter does to get the center blue div to extend down indefinitely....however this is not working on my application...are there any stipulations?